# Find shortest substring

Tags: python, substring

I have written a code to find the substring  from a string. It prints all substrings.
But I want a substring that ranges from length 2 to 6 and print the substring of minimum length.
Please help me

Program:

```
import re
p=re.compile('S(.+?)N')
s='ASDFANSAAAAAFGNDASMPRKYN'
s1=p.findall(s)
print s1
```

output:

```
['DFA', 'AAAAAFG', 'MPRKY']
```

Desired output:

```
'DFA'  length=3
```

Comment: What if there is more than 1 string of minimum length?

Comment: I don't know what constraints you have on your input, but you have to be careful with regular expressions. For example, with the string 'SASANSAAN', your regular expression will return ['ASA', 'AA']—when perhaps your desired output would have been 'A' (in 'SAN').

Answer (score 9):

If you already have the list, you can use the [min](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function with the [len](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) function as the second argument.

```
>>> s1 = ['DFA', 'AAAAAFG', 'MPRKY']
>>> min(s1, key=len)
'DFA'
```

**EDIT:**
In the event that two are the same length, you can extend this further to produce a list containing the elements that are all the same length:

```
>>> s2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs', 'knight']
>>> s2_min_len = len(min(s2, key=len))
>>> [e for e in s2 if len(e) is s2_min_len]
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

The above should work when there is only 1 'shortest' element too.

**EDIT 2:** Just to be complete, it should be faster, at least according to my simple tests, to compute the length of the shortest element and use that in the list comprehension. Updated above.

Answer (score 4):

The regex `'S(.{2,6}?)N'` will give you only matches with length 2 - 6 characters.

To return the shortest matching substring, use `sorted(s1, key=len)[0]`.

Full example:

```
import re
p=re.compile('S(.{2,6}?)N')
s='ASDFANSAAAAAFGNDASMPRKYNSAAN'
s1=p.findall(s)
if s1:
    print sorted(s1, key=len)[0]
    print min(s1, key=len) # as suggested by Nick Presta
```

This works by sorting the list returned by `findall` by length, then returning the first item in the sorted list.

Edit: Nick Presta's answer is more elegant, I was not aware that `min` also could take a `key` argument...